# How to add to a python dict in a loop, similar to PHP

Tags: php, python, dictionary, associative-array

So in php I can do the following to add to an assoc...

```
$data = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
   $data['items'][] = $item;
}
```

and I will have all the items, in the data array under the items key.

I want to do the exact same thing in Py, but cant seem to get the syntax/how to do it correctly.

```
data = {}
for metric in metrics:
  data['data'] = [
    {
      "Date": metric.date_created.strftime('%Y%m%d'),
      "Users": "1"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `]`, but any way I would use list comprehension to achieve this:

```
data = {}
data['data'] = [{'Date': metric.date_created.strftime('%Y%m%d'), "Users": "1"}
                for metric in metrics]
```

**Note that in your way you're overwriting `data['data']` in each iteration**, and in my example you actually create a list of dictionaries, each one for each iteration.

Comment: Yes, that was my issue (the overwriting).  The comprehension you posted was exactly what I needed.  I'm just getting started in Py, and was struggling to get the same behavior I am accustomed to in PHP.  Thank you very much!